# SwiftUI safeAreaInset causes glitches when using ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

#### Context

I have a custom navigation bar that transitions from a large to a small state depending on the scroll offset. Being a navigation bar, I initially implemented it with `safeAreaInset` but grew frustrated with scroll glitches that I couldn't resolve. Eventually, I thought I would try using a `VStack` instead and it worked.

#### Question

Why does using `safeAreaInset` like:

```swift
content.safeAreaInset(edge: .top) {
    MyNavigationView()
}
```

cause the glitches, while using a `VStack` work fine:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    MyNavigationView()
    content
}
```

The reason I ask is because `safeAreaInset` *feels* like the correct approach to this problem. But please advise if you disagree or have a better solution.

| VStack | SafeAreaInset |
| --- | --- |
| [image: VStack] | [image: SafeAreaInset] |

#### More Details

The screen body is, essentially, of the form:

```swift
var body: some View {
    OffsetScrollView(offset: $offset) {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
            content
        }
    }
    .modifier(NavigationBar(offset: offset))
}
```

The body of the `MyNavigationView` is along the lines of:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        SmallNavigationBar()

        // Clip to a proportional height based on scroll offset.
        // The vertical size of the large navigation bar should be fixed.
        Color.clear
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                LargeNavigationBar()
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .readHeight($largeNavigationBarHeight)
            }
            .frame(height: largeNavigationBarHeight * progress)
            .clipped()
    }
    .background(NavigationBarBackground())
}
```

where

- `OffsetScrollView` is a custom `ScrollView` that stores its offset into an `offset` state
- `NavigationBar` is a `ViewModifier` with one of the implementations in the question
- `progress` is a percentage of scroll offset which is used to linearly transition between states

Not needed for the question, but if anyone wants, this is on [Github](https://github.com/BenShutt/AdaptiveNavigationBar).

TIA.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] in your question, instead of linking to GitHub? Questions should be self-contained.

Comment: Hey @Sweeper, I tried to reduce my Q to only contain what was important; the Github link was only added as a reference. I have added a "More Details" section now since you felt like it was lacking detail, but I'm conscious of adding too much

Comment: I think it relates to how the views are built vs how you calculate which navigation bar to display. I think what happens with safe area is that your calculation returns sometimes "compact" and sometimes "large" when it redraws and readjusts safe area for display. It's a chicken and the egg: your calculation returns "compact", it starts drawing compact, which changes offset in the list, which causes it to decide that it should draw a large title, which causes redraw and so on.

Comment: You don't say how you calculate this, but one way to handle this would be to give a _range_ large enough so your calculation doesn't change its decision just because the safe area itself changed (and only changes on big enough changes in the list position)

Comment: Thanks @timbretimbre. I did think it might be a chicken-and-egg problem of sorts. Perhaps where the `ScrollView` is moving the safe area, which in turn affects the scroll content itself. Regarding your comment, the implementation doesn't switch between discrete states like you might be thinking, it's a linear transition via clipping the large bar by a proportional height. I added this detail to the Q though as it's important.